# How to fix "MasterPage is undefined" in javascript function?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I am currently supporting a web-based app in asp.net vb. This part of code below is for checking the session and automatically logs off the user after the expiration of session. Also, I have a security window that pops up upon the successful log in and also logs off the user whenever this pop up window is refreshed or closed.

The problem is I am having an error saying `"MasterPage is Undefined"` whenever the javascript is calling the functions in `MasterPage.master.vb`. The error occurs on code `MasterPage.LogOn()`, `MasterPage.GetClientSession()`, and the likes.

Below is my javascript in the MasterPage.master file and the functions `LogOn()`, `GetClientSession()` and others are on the MasterPage.master.vb file.
This issue only occurs upon the deployment of the system on the test server, and works fine on my local pc.

Anyone who can help please. Thanks so much.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
var SessionTime = 0;
var uname = "";
var status = "";
var clientSession = 0;
var spyOn;
function logon()
{
    MasterPage.LogOn();
    clientSession = MasterPage.GetClientSession().value;
    spyOn = MasterPage.spyOn().value;
    setTimeout("CheckSession()", 60000);
    if (!spyOn)
    {
        var spyWin = open('spy.aspx','UserSecurity','width=250,height=100,left=2000,top=2000,status=0,scrollbar=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no');
    }
}
function CheckSession()
{
    SessionTime = SessionTime + 1;
    if (SessionTime >= clientSession)
    {
        var uname = document.getElementById("ctl00_hdnUser").value;
        var status = document.getElementById("ctl00_hdnStatus").value;
        var x = MasterPage.SessionEnded(uname, status).value;
        alert(x);
        window.open("Login.aspx","_self");
    }
    setTimeout("CheckSession()", 60000);
}

function RorC() 
{
    var top=self.screenTop; 
    if (top>9000) 
    {
        window.location.href="logout.aspx" ;
    }
} 

function LogMeOut()
{
  window.location.href="logout.aspx" ;
}

function ShowTime() 
{
    var dt = new Date();
    document.getElementById("<%= Textbox1.ClientID %>").value = dt.toLocaleTimeString();

    window.setTimeout("ShowTime()", 1000);
    MasterPage.CheckSession(CheckSession_CallBack);

}  
 window.setTimeout("ShowTime()", 1000);

function CheckSession_CallBack(response)
{
    var ret = response.value;
    if (ret == "")
    {
        isClose = true;
        window.location.href="login.aspx" 
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Already fixed this by adding handlers (<httphandlers> under <system.web> section and <handlers> under <system.webserver> section) on web.config that supports IIS7 and also setting the application pool on IIS manager from "Integrated"
 to "Classic".

Comment: glad you were able to solve this problem on your own, for others that may be searching for this later, could you submit your answer in the form of an answer? It's okay to answer your own questions!

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by adding handlers (`<httphandlers>` under `<system.web>` section and `<handlers>` under `<system.webserver>` section) on `web.config` that supports IIS7 and also setting the application pool on IIS manager from "Integrated" to "Classic".